# Unable to open default template of SSRS 2012 portal

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

This is the default view of the SSRS 2012. There is no option for "my subscription", folder settings, upload file, etc.

[image]

I am not sure if I have missed any settings while configuring SSRS.

Comment: You're on the wrong webpage. You're on http://YourServerName/ReportServer, not http://yourServerName/Reports

Comment: If I use /Reports, i am getting 500 - Internal server error

Comment: I suggest having a look at the SSRS logs then and posting those.

Comment: Ok will check the logs and post it

Comment: Close this question and open a new one as the real problem is not being able to access the web portal page.

Comment: @Larnu, Thank you for the suggestion to check logs. After checking the logs I re-configured the SSRS portal using "Reporting Services Configuration Manager" and used servername/Reports instead of servername/reportserver as the URL.

Comment: So, how do you access the webpage you previously had now @Satyakam ..?

Comment: I accessed using servername/Reports. I got the exact layout and the options i was looking for.